# Synchronizing with 3rd-party asynchronous API in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, promise, casperjs

Here I'm feeling stucked with some asynchronous code that should run inside a `casper.then()` callback.

```
casper.then(function() {
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
    var child = spawn("somecommand", ["somearg"]);
    child.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
      console.log("spawnSTDOUT:", JSON.stringify(data))
    });
});

casper.then(function () {
  // Something that should be synchonized
});
```

Is there any way to make sure that the second `then()` will be executed only after the data callback fires up?

I'd love to replace the first `then()` with something that will not pass the control to second `then()` after execution by default, and would rather do this by calling something (let's call it 'resolve' as the promise pattern suggests) in the data callback.

Examples that are making use of `casper.waitFor()` are also appreciated, but I'd receive a sort of 'common practice' suggestion in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until the child process exits. This is usually done with a (global) variable. It is set in the event of an "exit" of the child process and the subsequent `casper.waitFor()` will wait until that variable is truthy. You may need to adjust the timeout.

```
casper.then(function() {
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
    var child = spawn("somecommand", ["somearg"]);
    child.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
      console.log("spawnSTDOUT:", JSON.stringify(data))
    });

    var childHasExited = false;
    child.on("exit", function (code) {
      childHasExited = true;
    })

    this.waitFor(function check(){
      return childHasExited;
    }, null, null, 12345); // TODO: adjust the timeout
});

casper.then(function () {
  // Something that should be synchonized
});
```

CasperJS' scripting isn't really based on promises which is why `waitFor()` must be used. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30129100/1816580) for more.

Instead of `casper.waitFor()` you can use an infinite waitFor:

```
casper.infWaitFor = function(check, then) {
    this.waitFor(check, then, function onTimeout(){
        this.infWaitFor(check, then);
    });
    return this;
}
```