# JavaScript/CasperJS handling of timeouts when looping over pages

Tags: javascript, settimeout, casperjs

I have a problem with this script. It is supposed to load some links (line by line) saved in prova.txt then pass the links one by one to CasperJS and get the html of the page. I know that there must be some problem with timeouts/JavaScript.

Here is the script:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file_h = fs.open('prova.txt', 'r');
var line = file_h.readLine();
var links = new Array();
var casper = require('casper').create();

while(line) {
    line = file_h.readLine();
    links.push(line);
}

(function theLoop (i) {
    console.log("LOOP");
    casper.start(links[i], function() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            fs.write("stats" + i + ".html", this.getHTML() );
            i = i + 1;
            if (--i) {
                theLoop(i);
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
    casper.run();
})(4);
```

Documentation that I used: http://scottiestech.info/2014/07/01/javascript-fun-looping-with-a-delay/

Comment: Documentation that I used: http://scottiestech.info/2014/07/01/javascript-fun-looping-with-a-delay/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't call `start` and `run` multiple times on the same `casper` instance.**

```
casper.start();

(function theLoop (i) {
    console.log("LOOP");
    casper.thenOpen(links[i], function() {
        this.wait(2000, function () {
            fs.write("stats" + i + ".html", this.getHTML() );
            if (--i) {
                theLoop(i);
            }
        });
    });
})(4);

casper.run();
```

Additionally, it seems like you want to decrease `i` to 0, so you shouldn't increment (`i = i + 1`) and decrement it `--i` in the next line.

Keep in mind that if you use `setTimeout` in a CasperJS script, you're breaking out of the stepped control flow and have to catch the broken off execution somehow. Use CasperJS' capabilities until it becomes inevitable. For example, I replaced `setTimeout(function(){}, x)` with `casper.wait(x, function(){})`.

Comment: About i, yeah that's a big mistake by myself... thank you. But what do you mean with start and run? Wich one I have to remove and how to do it?

Comment: The code I've provided should work. I've also found another issue in the mean time.

Comment: Thank you it works ;) Now I just need to understand where is the big change looking at my previous code..

Comment: I moved `start` and `run` out of the recursive function into global scope, fixed the `i++`/`--i` issue and stayed in the control flow. If you want to understand more about how CasperJS' steps work, then look at my answer here: [What must be wrapped in then() statements in CasperJS? How to determine execution order of sync/async functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30129100/1816580)