# CasperJS posting only the last item multiple times from my for-loop

Tags: javascript, loops, post, phantomjs, casperjs

CasperJS is awesome but it's not posting to my localhost what my console output is.

```
casper.wait(5000, function () {
    casper.wait(1000, function () {
        casper.then(function(){
            for  (var i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
                var description = casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="acDataId-local'+i+'"]/a')); //*[@id="acDataId-local0"]/a
                console.log(description);
                var target_date = casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="dtDataId-local'+i+'"]/text()[1]')); 
                console.log(target_date);
                var target_location = casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="veDataId-local'+i+'"]')); 
                console.log(target_location);

                console.log(i, description)

                casper.then(function () {

                    casper.open('http://localhost:1337/events', {
                        method: 'post',
                            data:   {
                            'description': description,
                            'target_date':  target_date,
                            'target_location':  target_location,
                        },
                        headers: {
                           "stuff":"stuff"
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
            this.echo('POST ' + i );
        });
    });
});


casper.run();
```

Console.log is outputting exactly when I want but it is only posting the last item.  I tried to add casper.wait in a variety of places but it didn't seem to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `then*` and `wait*` functions in CasperJS are [asynchronous step functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30129100/1816580) and [JavaScript has function-level scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1816580).

This means that the for-loop is executed immediately and several `then()` steps are scheduled to be executed after the for-loop is completely finished. At that point the function-level variables `description`, `target_date`, etc. will all have the value of the last `i` and `i` will be 10. Here is a general JavaScript example of that: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

You can either

- change the two calls `casper.then()` and `casper.open()` to a single call `casper.thenOpen()` where the loop variables are passed to the function directly:

  ```
  casper.thenOpen('http://localhost:1337/events', {
      method: 'post',
          data:   {
          'description': description,
          'target_date':  target_date,
          'target_location':  target_location,
      },
      headers: {
         "stuff":"stuff"
      }
  });
  ```
- or "close" the variables for each iteration by introducing an IIFE:

  ```
  for  (var i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
      (function(){
          var description = casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="acDataId-local'+i+'"]/a')); //*[@id="acDataId-local0"]/a
          console.log(description);
          var target_date = casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="dtDataId-local'+i+'"]/text()[1]')); 
          console.log(target_date);
          var target_location = casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="veDataId-local'+i+'"]')); 
          console.log(target_location);


          console.log(i, description)


          casper.then(function () {

              casper.open('http://localhost:1337/events', {
                  method: 'post',
                      data:   {
                      'description': description,
                      'target_date':  target_date,
                      'target_location':  target_location,
                  },
                  headers: {
                     "stuff":"stuff"
                  }
              });
          });
      })();
  }
  ```

Comment: Dope, Appreciate the thorough response.  Very helpful.