# How to call an async function inside then() in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, casperjs

I have a scenario in which I need to call APIs during a Casper test. In order to call these APIs, I'm thinking of using `then()`.

The problem is that **Casper doesn't wait** whatever I pass to `then()`, even if I return a Promise like this:

```
casper.then(function() {
    return new Promise(function(f, r) {
       setTimeout(function() {
           console.log('waited 10 secs');
           f();
       }, 10000)
});});
```

How can I make Casper wait inside the function I pass to `then()`?

Comment: @dandavis that's exactly what he did

Comment: `then` of [CasperJS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30129100/6445533) seems to be incompatible with ES6 `Promise`