# How to make correct loop in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration, casperjs

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start();


casper.then(function(){
    for(var i=1;i<3;i++){
        this.repeat(3,function(){
            this.echo("loop iteration!");
        });
        this.echo("hello"); 
    }
});

casper.run()
```

Output:

> hello hello loop iteration! loop iteration! loop iteration! loop iteration! loop iteration! loop iteration!

Why does "hello" print first?

How to write loop as synchronize loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What must be wrapped in then() statements in CasperJS? How to determine execution order of sync/async functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105017/what-must-be-wrapped-in-then-statements-in-casperjs-how-to-determine-executio)

Answer (score 0):

Artjom is correct. You have to use then(). Something like:

```
for(var i=1;i<3;i++){
        this.repeat(3,function(){
            this.echo("loop iteration!");
        });
        this.then(function(){
                this.echo("hello");
        });
}
```